# Why Simple Knockout js does not work in desktop and works in Fiddle

Tags: knockout.js

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.js"/>
<script src="knockoutdebug.js"/>
<script type='text/javascript'>

// Class to represent a row in the seat reservations grid
function SeatReservation(papers) {
    var self = this;
    //self.name = name;
    self.papers = ko.observable(papers);
}

// Overall viewmodel for this screen, along with initial state
function ReservationsViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    // Non-editable catalog data - would come from the server
    self.availableMeals = [
        {   title: "Ethics in HCI", 
            authors: "Rolf" , 
            abstract:"Users ."
        },
        { title: "HCI", authors: "Lynnl"  },
        { title: "Eth", authors: "Rolson"  }
    ];    

    // Editable data
    self.seats = ko.observableArray([
        new SeatReservation( self.availableMeals[0]),
        new SeatReservation(self.availableMeals[1])
    ]);
}

ko.applyBindings(new ReservationsViewModel());
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>
  <input type="search" id="skyquery" name="q" placeholder="scientific search" autofocus />
  <input type="submit" id="skysubmit" value="Ignite!" />
</p>
<table>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: seats">
        <tr data-bind="text: papers().title"/>
        <tr data-bind="text: papers().authors"/>
        <tr data-bind="text: papers().abstract"/>
    </tbody>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my code which i created using Knockout sample code. But the firbug does not thowo any errors. Nothing happens. But when i try in their fiddle it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ko.applyBindings` needs to be called after the DOM elements (with the `data-bind` attributes) are created.

To fix this, you can either move your `script` tag to the bottom of the page or wrap it in `$(document).ready()`.

Perhaps the reason its working in jsfiddle is because its set up to run the JavaScript onDOMReady.

Answer (score 2):

It might be because the `ko.applyBindings(new ReservationsViewModel());` is executing before the DOM has rendered.  Make it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ko.applyBindings(new ReservationsViewModel());
});
```